# Javascript built in codepen doesn’t work on my own website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, click

I built a simple random quote generator as part of a learning program.

On codepen.io my code worked perfectly. I built a single (& simple) function in javascript (jQuery) that rendered a random quote (stored in an array) along with the author in pre-defined html elements.

I then made sure that my function would run as the page was loaded, and also when the button was clicked.

This is the codepen.io page of my project, fully functional
https://codepen.io/empathies/pen/NWRvXKK

This is the link to the page I put online
http://empathies.eu/FreeCodeCamp/random-quote-generator.html

When the page is loaded a random quote is shown, proving that my html page can access my Javascript file (in a different folder), but when I click the button on my page nothing happens.

Here is the content of my .js file (declaration of my “quotes” array is just above in the file)

```
const generateQuote = function() {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  $("#text").fadeOut(function () {$('#text').text(quotes[random][0])}).fadeIn();
  $("#author").fadeOut(function () {$('#author').text(quotes[random][1])}).fadeIn();
}



$(document).ready(generateQuote);
$("#new-quote").click(generateQuote);
```

The document ready line is excecuted, but the click-event is completely ignored.

Can anybody help me solve this mystery?

Comment: You need to load your script at the bottom of the page. Right now it's at your head, so when it loads, it cant find the `new-quote` element

Comment: Move `<script src="../javascript/random-quote-generator.js"></script>` down just before `</body>`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen - Yeah, I got there. :-) Thanks. If you have a dupehammer (surely you do), here's the canonical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element (I was silly and voted to close using a different reason, off my game today.)

Comment: I moved the <script> like to my js file to the bottom of the page.
Works perfectly now! thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments my mistake was found.
I linked to my .js filed at the top of my html page meaning the script was loaded before the button was present in my page.

I moved my  link to the bottom of the page meaning it's loaded after the creation of my button element.
Now it works perfectly.